# How to make adaptive iFrame height?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, web-applications

I'm trying to make iFrame adaptive according to window size. I almost done but in phone mode it's breaking, no idea why. I used a lot of examples about how to align iFrame, but no one worked well. Also, a space what you can see on screenshot below doesn't appears in html or css, and it seems like this space is out of body or html, at all. Any ideas what could that be? I'm using asp.net core web application with razor pages. iFrame is inside div tag what's inside main tag
[image]

Here's my css code

```
.AdaptiveIframe iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.AdaptiveIframe {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

html

```
<main role="main">
    <div class="AdaptiveIframe">
        <iframe frameborder="0">Oops! Your browser does not support iframe.</iframe>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
</main>
```

Comment: remove the height on the relative container class - the padding will give the container the height

Comment: thanks for your replying, I've posted the answer below, but I'm welcome anything you think is better to fix

Answer (score 0):

I've suddenly found an answer. Here's my css code. But I'm welcome any suggestions if there's still anything to fix.

```
.AdaptiveIframe iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
}

.AdaptiveIframe {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 150%;
}
```